# How to get the coordinates of the bounding box in YOLO while Object is detecting

Tags: python, object-detection

I'm trying to get coordinates of the object to print while it's detecting I am using this example https://github.com/simaiden/Clothing-Detection.

This is the link where my python file that I running for object detection

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LX4mLVa1Si7HwFS8Wh70hQL1lKxXQhS_?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please post your code as text instead of a link?

Comment: @shaedrich iam not able to post the code its give me some errors so if you don't mind can you look at the google link, please

Comment: I mind but others probably don't.